# Error While Try To Install s3cmd Tool for S3

Tags: s3cmd

I am actually trying to install s3cmd tool that has been cloned from git. I have python 3 installed on my node and it looks while trying to install it gives some Error ::

```
    [root@linux s3cmd]# /opt/python3/bin/python3 setup.py install
  File "setup.py", line 18
    print "Using xml.etree.ElementTree for XML processing"
                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[root@linux s3cmd]#
```

Is it I am missing any supporting Library. The base Operating System is RHEL 6.6

Thanks.

Comment: I have the same error, this definitely looks like a python 3 compatibility issue as the print line is missing a paranthesis

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer on the package's site FAQ. This package isn't yet compatible with Python 3.

http://s3tools.org/kb/item17.htm